# Examples of Isomorphic Real and Complex Lie Groups

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Are there any examples of common (for example SL, SO, SU, GL groups of varying dimension) real and complex Lie groups which are isomorphic? I'm aware that many Lie groups are of odd dimension which would stop an argument being made by taking a real manifold and showing it's equivalent to a complex one but writing about some of these groups (e.g. SO and SU) often it isn't explicitly stated whether they are real or complex Lie groups.

In the case of $GL(\mathbb{C},n)$ and $GL(\mathbb{R},n)$ as the former is of dimension $2n^2$ and the latter $n^2$ assume no GL groups can be isomorphic as they cannot have the same dimension. I'm not sure however if dimension stops something being isomorphic as a group (certainly they are not isomorphic as manifolds).

Comment: Hint – do these groups have the same dimension (over $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: @Mindlack Right, one has (real) dimension $2n^2$ and the other $4n^2$ so assumedly no GL groups can be isomorphic as there is no integer square root of 2?

Comment: Do you mean, is there a complex Lie group $G$ and a real Lie group $H$ such that the real Lie group (or just real manifold) underlying $G$ is isomorphic to $H$? This seems to be answered by, well, take any complex Lie group and check what underlying real Lie group you get when forgetting the complex structure. For example, $(\mathbb C,+) \simeq (\mathbb R^2,+)$.

Comment: Or maybe are you asking a much more restricted but less trivially answerable question, namely, if the underlying real Lie group of any "classical" complex Lie group happens to also be a "classical" real Lie group?

Comment: By the way I agree that especially with $SO$ people are often not clear enough whether they mean $SO(\mathbb C)$ or $SO(\mathbb R)$, which can make a really complex difference. With $SU$ on the other hand, in 95% of cases it's safe to assume it is a *real* Lie group, because that's the standard way it is defined. -- And also, if you are studying *algebraic* groups, then early on in the theory it is crucial to understand the difference between the algebraic group (scheme) like $GL, SO, ...$ and "its points" $GL(k), SO(k), ...$ over some field $k$, possibly $k= \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I suppose what I mean to ask is if any complex/real Lie algebras I might already be familiar with are isomorphic (as groups) hence why I was comparing GL, SO and SU groups. I assume this is what you're referring to by "classical" groups in your second comment. I've edited the question to clarify in response to the comments made thus far.

Comment: If you're asking for isomorphisms as groups, ignoring manifold structure, all hell breaks loose, for starters all $\mathbb R^n$ ($n \ge 1$) are isomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noticed in comments, this question is a bit too vague and the answer is, in one way, simple ("well, look at all complex Lie groups you know and check what real Lie group you get when you forget the complex structure"), and in one way difficult (because now you would need to know all real Lie groups up to isomorphism, which are ... many).

Because of your insistence on some author's flaw to write, for example, $SO_n$ and to not make it sufficiently clear whether they mean the complex Lie group $SO_n(\mathbb C)$ or the real Lie group $SO_n(\mathbb R)$, it just occurred to me that you might ask if that ever does not make a big difference, i.e. whether one ever has an isomorphism of underlying real Lie groups like $$SO_n(\mathbb R) \stackrel{?}\simeq SO_n(\mathbb C)$$ or $$GL_n(\mathbb R) \stackrel{?}\simeq GL_n(\mathbb C)$$ or $$SL_n(\mathbb R) \stackrel{?}\simeq SL_n(\mathbb C)$$
with **the same** algebraic group and **the same $n$** on both sides?? Well, with possible trivial exceptions for $n=1$ in some cases, easy dimension considerations should rule out that any of such isomorphisms would ever exist, even on the manifold level. So no, if an author is imprecise there, it's really their fault.

The question becomes interesting if one allows for a little more vagueness, and asks for possible "exceptional" isomorphism (cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/81344/27465) with a complex Lie group on the one side and a classical real Lie group on the other. I.e., can something like $SO_{7}(\mathbb C) \stackrel{?}\simeq SL_{12}(\mathbb R)$ ever happen? Well, the first (but only) standard example is

$$SL_2(\mathbb C) \simeq Spin(1,3)$$

(as real Lie groups), i.e. forgetting the complex structure on the left hand side gives us a real Spin group (which happens to be the double cover of the indefinite special orthogonal group $SO(1,3)$, all this higly related to the Lorentz group and thus of interest to physics). In particular as **real** Lie algebras,

$$\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(1,3).$$

Actually, on the Lie algebra level the question will be generally answerable in the semisimple case, as the Satake-Tits diagram of the underlying real Lie algebra of any semisimple complex Lie algebra just consists of two copies of the Dynkin diagram of the complex one, with arrow between them. With the exception of the above (where $A_1 \times A_1$ happens to be $D_2$, and the arrow between these two unconnected nodes tells us we are in a quasi-split case), none of these "two copies of a Dynkin diagram connected with arrows" have a different "classical" name, as far as I know.